# Combine two arrays into an object in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, lodash

```
column_names: [
    "School Year Ending",
    "Total Students",
    "American Indian/Alaskan Native: Total",
    "American Indian/Alaskan Native: Male",
    "American Indian/Alaskan Native: Female",
    "Asian/Pacific Islander: Total",
    "Asian/Pacific Islander: Male",
    "Asian/Pacific Islander: Female",
    "Hispanic: Total",
    "Hispanic: Male",
    "Hispanic: Female",
    "Black: Total",
    "Black: Male",
    "Black: Female",
    "White: Total",
    "White: Male",
    "White: Female"
],
data: [
    "2011-12-31",
    3471888,
    39433,
    19926,
    19507,
    182697,
    94104,
    88593,
    686081,
    344910,
    341171,
    536271,
    260720,
    275551,
    1970983,
    1006592,
    964391
]
```

Is there some way to turn these two JSON arrays into an object format?  For instance:

```
"School Year Ending": "2011-12-31",
"Total Students": 3721888,
...
```

I'd prefer to do this using a lo-dash function for convenience.  Is there something like this?

Comment: Please note that your example is not JSON. It looks like a JS array/object. I believe your problem has nothing to do with JSON at all.

Comment: It does Felix, I just copied part of the JSON return to show here.  The structure was long an non-pertinent to the question so I took a sample.

Comment: It doesn't really matter where the data came from. It looks like you want to combine two JS arrays to a JS object. The answer you selected for example doesn't have anything to do with JSON either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
_.zipObject(column_names, data);
```

should do it.

Comment: All the other answers works, but this one was in lo-dash which I requested.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I believe this will do it in plain JS.

```
var columns = { };
for (var i in column_names) 
    columns[column_names[i]] = data[i];
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8s7xd74w/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla JavaScript - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d81xk3yq/)

```
var column_names = [
    "School Year Ending",
    "Total Students",
    "American Indian/Alaskan Native: Total",
    "American Indian/Alaskan Native: Male",
    "American Indian/Alaskan Native: Female",
    "Asian/Pacific Islander: Total",
    "Asian/Pacific Islander: Male",
    "Asian/Pacific Islander: Female",
    "Hispanic: Total",
    "Hispanic: Male",
    "Hispanic: Female",
    "Black: Total",
    "Black: Male",
    "Black: Female",
    "White: Total",
    "White: Male",
    "White: Female"
],
data = [
    "2011-12-31",
    3471888,
    39433,
    19926,
    19507,
    182697,
    94104,
    88593,
    686081,
    344910,
    341171,
    536271,
    260720,
    275551,
    1970983,
    1006592,
    964391
],
obj = {};

for (var i = 0, l = column_names.length; i < l; i += 1) {
    obj[column_names[i]] = data[i]
}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

And yet another solutions with vanilla JS! This uses forEach

http://jsfiddle.net/w5f36jwd/

```
school_data = {
    column_names:
    [
        "School Year Ending",
        "Total Students",
        "American Indian/Alaskan Native: Total",
        "American Indian/Alaskan Native: Male",
        "American Indian/Alaskan Native: Female",
        "Asian/Pacific Islander: Total",
        "Asian/Pacific Islander: Male",
        "Asian/Pacific Islander: Female",
        "Hispanic: Total",
        "Hispanic: Male",
        "Hispanic: Female",
        "Black: Total",
        "Black: Male",
        "Black: Female",
        "White: Total",
        "White: Male",
        "White: Female"
    ],
    data:
    [
        "2011-12-31",
        3471888,
        39433,
        19926,
        19507,
        182697,
        94104,
        88593,
        686081,
        344910,
        341171,
        536271,
        260720,
        275551,
        1970983,
        1006592,
        964391
    ]
}

var new_object = {};

school_data.column_names.forEach(function(el, index, data_array){
    new_object[el] = school_data.data[index];
});

console.log(new_object);
```